# C++ for iphone crash

Tags: c++, iphone

Im developing a game engine for iphone in C++ but im getting a crash with my Matrix class. I hope you can see whats wrong because i stare my self blind on the crash.

```
/*
 * Copyright (c) 2010 Johnny Mast
 * 
 * Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person
 * obtaining a copy of this software and associated documentation
 * files (the "Software"), to deal in the Software without
 * restriction, including without limitation the rights to use,
 * copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
 * copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the
 * Software is furnished to do so, subject to the following
 * conditions:

 * The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be
 * included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
 * 
 * THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND,
 * EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES
 * OF MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND
 * NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT
 * HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY,
 * WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING
 * FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR
 * OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
 */

#include "Matrix.h"

Matrix::Matrix() {
 /*
 ** if this constuctor has been used you should call
 ** setWidth and setHeight before using this class.
 ** use of this constructor is not reconmended and it 
 ** will producse rended code.
 */
 matrixwidth  = 0;
 matrixheight = 0;
}

Matrix::Matrix(int width, int height) {
 matrixwidth  = width;
 matrixheight = height;
 setupMatrix();
}

void Matrix::setWidth(int width) {
 matrixwidth = width;
 setupMatrix();
}

void Matrix::setHeight(int height) {
 matrixheight = height;
 setupMatrix();
}

void Matrix::mark(int x, int y, int value) {
 NSLog(@"Marking");
 //matrix[x][y] = value;
 NSLog(@"Marked");
}

int Matrix::get(int x, int y) {
 return matrix[x][y]; 
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Private functions from here.

void Matrix::setupMatrix() {
 if (matrixwidth > 0 && matrixheight > 0) {
  for (int w = 0, h = 0; w < matrixwidth, h < matrixheight; w++, h++) {
   matrix[w][h] = 0;
  } 
 }
}
```

The crash is in setupMatrix().

Comment: You need to provide information about `matrix` member. That's probably your problem here.

Comment: A memory debugger (such as Valgrind) would probably help you with this kind of problem (although the answer has already been given).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have one visible problem and one invisible problem. First the invisible one.

The fact that you're crashing in `setupMatrix` is almost certainly because you haven't allocated enough (or any) space for the `matrix` array. We'll need to see where that's done to be certain but it's a fairly safe bet.

One possibility, if you're using a dynamic array, is to create it in the constructors thus (after setting up width and height members):

```
matrix = 0; // for default constructor.
setupMatrix();
```

Then, in, `setupMatrix`, create the actual matrix, something like (untested):

```
if (matrix != 0) delete[] matrix;                // to delete current.

if (matrixwidth * matrixheight == 0)
    matrix = 0;                                  // none desired.
else
    matrix = new int[matrixwidth][matrixheight]; // make new.

// Initialise matrix (see corrected code below)
```

keeping in mind that you may want to copy the old data in some cases.

---

The other problem is with your `for` loop in that function. It only sets up the diagonals  to 0, `matrix[0][0]`, `matrix[1][1]` and so on. It should be:

```
for (int w = 0; w < matrixwidth; w++) {
    for (int h = 0; h < matrixheight; h++) {
        matrix[w][h] = 0;
     }
 }
```

The other problem with the loop you had will be if you have non-square matrices. Since the value of the expression `a,b` is `b`, your loop:

```
for (int w = 0, h = 0; w < matrixwidth, h < matrixheight; w++, h++) {
```

will only exit when `h >= matrixheight`. If your matrix is higher than it is wide, you may well be running off the end of your array, even if it *is* allocated correctly.

Comment: Feel free to leave a comment explaining the downvote. If it's valid, I can fix the problem or delete the answer.

Comment: Seems like the right answer(s) to me.  I wonder why it was down-voted.

Comment: Thanks, guys. Of course, allowing multi-upvotes from each person would probably be even _more_ unfair than drive-by downvoting :-) I'm happy to get downvoted if there's something wrong with the answer - that's how a meritocracy works, after all. I'd just prefer to know what was wrong so I can fix (or delete if the answer is so bad as to be unfixable). It also educates me and others in the process.

Comment: Hey guys thanks for all the replies sorry i was sleeping the matrix variable is a int **.

Comment: @Johnny, okay, it's an `int**`. Are you creating storage for it (with `new`)? It really doesn't look like it based on the code you provided, in which case you should look at the first half of my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your loop:

```
for (int w = 0, h = 0; w < matrixwidth, h < matrixheight; w++, h++) 
{
   matrix[w][h] = 0;
}
```

The comma operator is not doing what you expect. This loops over the diagonal of the matrix and stops only when `h < matrixheight`. You need to write something like:

```
for (int i=0; i<width; ++i)
    for (int j=0; j<height; ++j)
        matrix[i][j] = 0;
```

Comment: Actually, it will stop when `h < matrixheight`. The expression `a, b` evaluates to `b`.

Comment: But this does not explain the crash or does it?

Comment: ik kinda did because i was writing to unallocated memory.